# SQL Connection problems (Wrong url?)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So I was testing out `MySQL` databases for the first time, (For the following code, all I want to do is establish a connection to the data base):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movie";
        String user = "root";
        String pw = "RockoAndLuke739969";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the **Exception**:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movie
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at Driver.main(Driver.java:13)

And I don't know why it isn't working.... thanks for taking your time to read :)
(I am new to stackoverflow by the way, so sorry if I screwed something up xD)

Comment: do you have jdbc jar on your classpath?

Comment: Add JDBC jar in the project libraries... it will work..

Comment: also add `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the driver in your classpath.
If you are using maven you have to add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

If you aren't using maven check your classpath manually and add the driver to it.

In addition add

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

as first line of your connection code. This line is needed to load the class driver and is used by `DriverManager` to know wich driver must be used.

Here the reference documentation [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was about to flip when it didn't work xD ( I would vote up your post but I don't have the perms)

Comment: You can click the up row and green flag. You should have the rights. You haven't rights to up vote your question, not the answers

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I really appreciate the quick response :)

Comment: Using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since 2006, with Java 6 (and a JDBC 4 compliant driver), using `.newInstance()` hasn't been necessary since - probably - the start of this century; that was only a workaround for a bug in the MySQL driver.